# Vue router how can i give query params on root page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:userId',
      name: 'top',
      component: Top
    }
  ]
})
```

I cannot give a query param like this.

Is it impossible to give param to root view?

```
export default new Router({
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/top/:userId',
          name: 'top',
          component: Top
        }
      ]
    })
```

I know this is possible , but I want to give param to root page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Root,
      children: [
      {
        path: ':userId',
        name: 'top',
        component: Top
      }
    }
  ]
})
```